# Lollypop plot with a Customizes Colour in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that consists of three (3) variables (Methods, lb and RMSE).

```
df1 <- data.frame(Methods = c('b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'), lb = c(9, 7, 9, 4, 9), RMSE = c(0.26177952, 0.11294586, 0.02452239, 0.08290467, 0.41488542))
df1

  Methods lb       RMSE
1       b  9 0.26177952
2       a  7 0.11294586
3       c  9 0.02452239
4       d  4 0.08290467
5       e  9 0.41488542
```

I want the Methods(a, b, c, d, e) to be arranged on the x-axis, the height of the  `lollypop plot` to correspond to the values of RMSE while the colours on the `lillyplot` to vary among the `lb` variable.

**I have tried this**

```
df1 |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = Methods, y = RMSE)) + ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
ggplot2::geom_segment(ggplot2::aes(x = Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
```

I got this [image]

```
df1 |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = Methods, y = RMSE)) + ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
ggplot2::geom_segment(ggplot2::aes(x = Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
ggplot2::theme_bw() + ggplot2::scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(5)))
```

When I changed from `manual` the image is still the same without colour.

**What I want**

I want the pop with colours such that I can customize the pop's colours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't really need to do `ggplot::` in all functions. It's just a syntax to make sure the functions you use are from the specific package `package::` you want. For `ggplot` functions, I'm pretty sure there's no conflicting function names.

Second, if you want `scale_fill_manual` to work, you need to use `aes(fill = var)` in `geom_function()` or `ggplot()`.

- If you want the `fill` or `colour` to apply to all `geom_*()` layers, use `ggplot(aes(fill = var))`.
- Otherwise, only use it in the desired `geom_*()` layer, which is in this case, in `geom_point(aes(color = var))` *(Note that in my code, I placed it in `ggplot`, so `geom_segment` is also coloured accordingly)*.

Third, since you're colouring `geom_point`, you should use `scale_color_manual` instead of `scale_fill_manual` (and also `aes(color = var)`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(Methods = c('b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'), lb = c(9, 7, 9, 4, 9), RMSE = c(0.26177952, 0.11294586, 0.02452239, 0.08290467, 0.41488542))

df1 |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Methods, y = RMSE, col = Methods)) + geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>