# Lollipop Plot: Customize Colours According to a Variable and the Lollipop Height According to Another Variable in a Data Frame Using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below data frame to demonstrate what I want.

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(Methods = c('b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'), lb = c(9, 7, 9, 4, 9), RMSE = c(0.26177952, 0.11294586, 0.02452239, 0.08290467, 0.41488542))

df1

  Methods lb       RMSE
1       b  9 0.26177952
2       a  7 0.11294586
3       c  9 0.02452239
4       d  4 0.08290467
5       e  9 0.41488542
```

An answer make the below [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871408/lollypop-plot-with-a-customizes-colour-in-r#71871479):

```
df1 |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Methods, y = RMSE, col = Methods)) + geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Here is the [image: output] of the R code above:

The lollipop plot simply reveals one thing which is the height of `RMSE`.

**What I Want**

1. In addition to the height of the `RMSE`, I want the colour to show the distribution of the `lb` column.
2. In the case of item 1 above, the `lb` variable (`9`, `7`, `9`, `4`, `9`) and values of `lb` should be attached to the chart legend.
3. I want the minimum value of the `lb` variable to carry `green` the next minimum to carry `yellowgreen`, the middle value to carry `yellow, the penultimate maximum to carry` orange`and the maximum value of the`lb`variable to carry`red`.
4. If two methods have the same value of `lb`, give them the same colour then continue to the next value of `lb` with the next colour.

The above is what I have summarized in the [image: below picture]:

Comment: Hi Daniel. Shouldn't `a`, `c` and `e` have the same colour? At least this is how I read 2)

Comment: Please refresh my question and check the 2 again

Comment: Why does it make sense to color 9 in three different colors?

Comment: @Quinten I have modified my question with respect to yours, please refresh this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  mutate(lb = as.factor(lb)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Methods, y = RMSE, colour = lb)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellow", "red")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I need your solution to work in a way that the ranking and colour placement will be done by `R` and not you reducing the number of your colours.

Comment: @Daniel James, If I understand you correctly, you can also remove the `scale_color_manual` which means that it will now automatically color.

Answer (score 1):

along these lines?

```
df1 |>
ggplot(aes(x = Methods, 
           xend = Methods,
           y = RMSE,
           yend = 0,
           col = cut(lb, 5, labels = c('XS','S','M','L','XL'))
           )
       ) +
geom_point(pch = 20, size = 4)+
geom_segment() +
scale_color_manual(values = c(XS = 'green', S = 'yellowgreen', 
                              M = 'yellow', L = 'orange', XL = 'red'))
```

edit: in case of tied **lb** levels, you could add a `rank`ed lb and use it for colouring like so:

```
df1 |>
mutate(lb_rank = rank(lb)) |>
ggplot(aes(x = Methods, 
           xend = Methods,
           y = RMSE,
           yend = 0,
           col = cut(lb_rank, 5,
                      labels = c('XS','S','M','L','XL'))
           )
       ) ## ... remaining stuff
```

Comment: I added 4th item to the existing 3 based on which you did answer the question.